# How can I add a custom calculated column during Azure Data Explorer Kusto CSV ingestion?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a CSV file with a column X containing "ID23857215326 anotherrandomtextaftertheid".

I only want to save the numeric ID as a real number during CSV ingestion.

How can this be done?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use an update policy:

- https://y0nil.github.io/kusto.blog/blog-posts/update-policies.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy

In your update policy query, you can use the "parse" operator:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator